# iOS Core Foundation - Analyze Warning

Tags: ios, foundation, core-foundation

I'm analyzing my app and get the following warning. Can someone help me out on this? All other errors are gone.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if (!self.isPresentationLayer) {
        self.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] init].scale;
    }

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    self.mainPath = (CGMutablePathRef)CGPathCreateCopy(path);

   CGContextSaveGState(context);

    [self customDrawInContext:context];
    [self drawMainPathImageInContext:context];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGPathRelease(path);

    self.isAllowedToAnimate = YES;
}
```

This is the warning message:

1.) Call to function 'CGPathCreateCopy' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count

2.) Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Comment: You mean self.mainPath?

Comment: I´m not that familar with it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: No i don´t think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77731/discussion-between-sven-janning-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
self.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] init].scale;
```

First, you don't need to `init`, because the main screen is a static property of `UIScreen` class. just write:

```
self.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Next, I think the problem is related to your property storage type.

When you write:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if (!self.isPresentationLayer) {
        self.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] init].scale;
    }

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    // path as +1 retainCount because of 'create'

    self.mainPath = (CGMutablePathRef)CGPathCreateCopy(path);
    // self.mainPath as +1 retainCount because of 'copy'
    // self.mainPath as again +1 retainCount if the property storage type is retain, copy or strong (I think the error is here)

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    [self customDrawInContext:context];
    [self drawMainPathImageInContext:context];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGPathRelease(path);
    // path as -1 retainCount and so is released.

    self.isAllowedToAnimate = YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i don´t know how to fix it.

Comment: If your property is strong/retain/copy, just write: `self.mainPath = path;` instead of `self.mainPath = (CGMutablePathRef)CGPathCreateCopy(path);`. The property will retain the value and your can release it safely at the end, like you're already doing.

Comment: Great - no the message dissapper.

Comment: I think it is "now the message disappear" :-) Don't hesitate to accept my answer as the response.